# Visualize a hack/attack with multiple attackers

Tags: nmap, penetration-testing, metasploit

For work I have to set up a challenge where we have 3 attackers and 1 victim. The victim will be running Metasploitable and the attackers Kali Linux. I need to find a way to visualize what is happening, in (close to) realtime, so others in the room can watch what happens.

What I'm most interested in is being able to see incomming port scans (nmap) and all commands entered on the victim machine. I have read about tty cloners and 'screen' but if an attackers uses metasploit to open a session, I want to see that too.

Basically what I need is a software solution which can give me all the info on 1 screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check out http://www.fudgie.org

Also, look at this tool: http://www.verend.com/projectsindex0.html called *netviz* with video demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDsA0wy4tps

Answer (score 0):

[Cobalt Strike](http://www.advancedpentest.com/) from Raphael Mudge may be your answer. From the demonstrations I've seen of it, it seems like the best tool to demonstrate what you're talking about. It does have features for collaboration (though they may be commercial only), and it definitely makes things look pretty. I highly recommend requesting for a trial.

However, if you don't have time to wait for them to respond with a trial copy, I would also suggest [Armitage](http://www.fastandeasyhacking.com/) - Cobalt Strike's younger brother, as some call it.